# Debugging with Swift & Xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Why `po` returns these strange errors? (with Xcode 6.4 & Swift)

I try to debug with `p` / `po`:

NSDictionary, String and NSNumber all getting similar kind of errors all the time.

For now, I use println() but I am curious what could be the reason?

```
 error: A fatal parse error has occurred.  LLDB may become unstable; please restart your debug session as soon as possible.

 error: <EXPR>:1:11: error: use of undeclared type '$__lldb_context'
 extension $__lldb_context {                            
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 <EXPR>:11:5: error: use of unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
 $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_7(
 ^
```

Comment: what were you trying to `po`?

Comment: @iosDev82: NSDictionary

Comment: @AiOsN Please update your question to clear. What, when, where your try with `po` or take a screenshot when you debugging.

Comment: @longpham: I try to debug with p / po:

NSDictionary, String and NSNumber all getting similar kind of errors all the time, For now, I use println() but I am curious what could be the reason?

Comment: @AiOsN I need more information. Can you add your code snippet?

Comment: @longpham here is some code

`for dic in dataArray
                {
                    var obj = Shop()
                    let dictionary = dic as! NSDictionary

                    println(dictionary)

                    if let email = dictionary[RESPONSE_EMAIL] as? String
                    {
                        println(email)
                        obj.email = email
  ...`

Comment: @longpham its also dictionary:  if let dic = response as? NSDictionary

Comment: @longpham: if its working fine with println(dictionary) it should work with po as well

Answer (score -1):

For swift language use **println()** method.For debugging in console you have to keep in mind that you can only get debug info for swift's variables, but can't get it for swift's constants. So change **let someVariable** to **var someVariable**.

then in debugger do **po someVarible**. It will work.

If it doesn't work for arrays & dictionary ,for arrays do something like **po print(myArray)**. Same goes for dictionary.

Comment: thanks for answer but this is not what i asked, I am wondering how to do debugger output on console with po / p

 println() is working fine.

Comment: Make sure you are using "po" for swift's variables not constants. You can only get debug info for swift's variables, but can't get it for swift's constants.

Comment: change your "let" to "var"

Comment: for array use "po print(myArray)" same goes for dictionary

Comment: @Muhammad_Awaab Wrong, `po` works with `let` too... just test, you'll see. ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxeXQnIYYZIS5_Lh138h6JolpgtWsYlOEs))

Comment: @EricD. You are correct indeed, it works with both let and var. I created new project and test both myself already, they are working fine, but in existing project it just do not work and I don't understand why because there is no proper errors message as well.